# problem with comparing string with '{' sign

Tags: python

I have problem with compare string with '{' sign. I used incrementation to go forward through string and if function find '{' or '}' should add sign to list. Unfortunately, the output is "IndexError: string index out of range". Do you have ideas how to do this?

```
while i <= len(summary):
    if summary[i] == '{':
        nws_otw.append(summary[i])
    if summary[i] == '}':
        nws_zam.append(summary[i])
    i+=1
```

Comment: You should iterate over the string using a `for ... in ...` loop. The reason you’re getting the error is because the last index in a list or string is the length minus 1.

Comment: You should use `i < len(summary)` instead `i <= len(summary)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the strings start with index 0, it is incorrect to iterate through the string using `while i <= len(summary):`, you should use `while i < len(summary):` instead.

Better yet is to use something like:

```
for i in range(len(summary)):
```

Answer (score 1):

The last index of a string or list is `len() - 1`. You should probably use a `for ... in ...` loop anyway. In fact, you can get rid of the loop entirely by checking if a substring is in a string using `sub in my_string`.

Answer (score 0):

I see that you didn't say what 'i' should start at either. It needs to be initialized before being used in the while loop. I posted some example code here, that works.

```
summary = "{This is some text}"
nws_otw = []
nws_zam = []
i = 0  # Needs to be present
while i < len(summary):
    if summary[i] == "{":
        nws_otw.append(summary[i])
    if summary[i] == "}":
        nws_zam.append(summary[i])
    i += 1
```